# Xcode 4 Interface Builder - prevent hierarchy changes on positioning

Tags: view, xcode4, interface-builder

I have a UIImageView and as I am positioning it, it keeps wanted to become a subview of other views on the viewController.  How do I stop it from doing this as I only want to reposition it and have it stay in the current hierarchy.  As of now, I have to enter the coordinates manually which is a pain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complete @Lucase's answer, you can double click the element in the 'left icon side bar' to make it movable by arrow key, elaborated in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823403/xcode-4-is-there-something-in-interface-builder-like-reveal-in-canvas/7823698#7823698).

Comment: Thanks for the double click suggestion. This was driving me crazy!

Comment: Also note that [arrow key] will nudge pixel by pixel, and [Shift]+[arrow key] moves 5 pixels at once.

Comment: You need to take some care to ensure you double click the item rather than start to edit the item's name, which you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is an oversight on the part of the Developer Tools team at Apple. You should file a bug http://bugreport.apple.com.

The best—albeit still annoying—way to get around this is to just use the arrow keys to nudge the view around. Or drag the view as close as you can get it without it being embedded in another view, then use the arrow keys to nudge the view around manually.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I didn't know about the nudging, that is still better then punching in coordinates.