# Xcode 4 - Is there something in Interface Builder like "reveal in canvas"?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, interface-builder

I have a fairly complex xib with many elements. Some of them are on top of each other. If I want to move an element for example by using the arrow-keys I need to select it in the canvas, but if that element is "under" another, I can't click on it. So I'm looking for the "opposite" of "Reveal in Document Outline". In Xcode 3 there was a shortcut for that, sadly I forgot it and can't find it anywhere. Maybe that still works in Xcode 4...

Does anyone know that shortcut? Or even a better way to "click on covered elements"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you expand the icon sidebar thing to the left (sorry, don't know what it's called, and I'm not able to do a screenshot at the moment) it will show you a heirarchy of all your objects in the nib. **Double Click** on one of those and it will be selected and movable.

Other methods are:

If you select an object in the canvas (so the resize / move handles are showing) you can tab from one object to the next. The selection does move in the document outline to indicate this.

Also, you can move objects by one-pixel increments by selecting them in the document navigator and going to the Size inspector, you can then adjust the X and Y of the layout rectangle using the stepper controls.

Comment: If you mean the Dock/Document Outline, thats not working. If you select sth there it gets marked in the canvas but if you then use the arrow-keys you just move through the hierarchy. In Xcode 3 there was a shortcut to get from a selection in the outline to a "real" selection in the canvas.

Comment: @Tobi, my apologies - I was answering on my phone and couldn't check it properly. I have updated my answer. You have to double click, not single click.

Comment: I've been looking for this feature (double click to select so you can nudge it with arrow keys) for months! Working, thanks!